# Python printing sequence in order through thread synchronization

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to make 5 sequences, each labeled 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and I want them to print in order such that the final result is like 0123401234....
The problem with my code below is that when I run it it shows "cannot notify an un-acquired condition". What is the issue?

```
n = 5 # num threads
threads = []
conds = []

def p(i):
    for _ in range(10):
        conds[i].acquire()
        conds[i].wait()
        print(i)
        conds[(i+1)%n].notify()
        conds[i].release()

for i in range(n):
    threads.append(Thread(target=p, args=[i]))

for i in range(n):
    conds.append(Condition())

for i in range(n):
    threads[i].start()

conds[0].notify()

for i in range(n):
    threads[i].join()

print("all done")
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-97b50cfecd78> in <module>
     22     threads[i].start()
     23 
---> 24 conds[0].notify()
     25 
     26 for i in range(n):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py in notify(self, n)
    350         """
    351         if not self._is_owned():
--> 352             raise RuntimeError("cannot notify on un-acquired lock")
    353         all_waiters = self._waiters
    354         waiters_to_notify = _deque(_islice(all_waiters, n))

RuntimeError: cannot notify on un-acquired lock
```

Comment: why do you use `(i+1)%n` ?

Comment: maybe you should use `conds[0].acquire()` before `conds[0].notify()` which makes problem.

Comment: @furas I don't really get the concept here—why do I need to acquire the lock#0 again if thread#0 acquired the lock and is waiting already? Does this mean that the code won't work if I don't use an RLock for Condition?

Comment: @PirloLochisomo Locking is to ensure thread safety of the _waiters variable of the Condition object

Answer (score 1):

Code works for me if I use `with`

```
from threading import Thread, Condition

n = 5 # num threads
threads = []
conds = []

def p(i):
    for _ in range(10):
        with conds[i]:
            conds[i].wait()

        print(i)

        with conds[(i+1)%n]:
            conds[(i+1)%n].notify()

for i in range(n):
    threads.append(Thread(target=p, args=[i]))

for i in range(n):
    conds.append(Condition())

for i in range(n):
    threads[i].start()

with conds[0]:
    conds[0].notify()

for i in range(n):
    threads[i].join()

print("all done")
```

And it realized me that it needs `acquire()` and `release()` with every `notify()`

```
conds[0].acquire()
conds[0].notify()
conds[0].release()
```

and

```
conds[(i+1)%n].acquire()
conds[(i+1)%n].notify()
conds[(i+1)%n].release()
```

```
from threading import Thread, Condition

n = 5 # num threads
threads = []
conds = []

def p(i):
    for _ in range(10):
        conds[i].acquire()
        conds[i].wait()
        conds[i].release()

        print(i)

        conds[(i+1)%n].acquire()
        conds[(i+1)%n].notify()
        conds[(i+1)%n].release()


for i in range(n):
    threads.append(Thread(target=p, args=[i]))

for i in range(n):
    conds.append(Condition())

for i in range(n):
    threads[i].start()

conds[0].acquire()
conds[0].notify()
conds[0].release()

for i in range(n):
    threads[i].join()

print("all done")
```

Comment: I see. I thought that since Thread#0 acquired the lock and is waiting already after the start(), I can just call its cond and notify(). So I even need to acquire the lock again outside just to call conds[0].notify()? Does that mean this code won't work if Condition's underlying lock isn't an RLock?

Comment: I have no idea - I use Condition first time.

Comment: @PirloLochisomo Regardless of whether your Condition passes RLock or not, conds[0].notify() will always release the mutex Lock, you can look at the code of the condition's wait method`waiter = _allocate_lock()`

Answer (score 1):

If there is no special reason, you can actually do it with lock

[wrong output] When adding time after while, it will cause output error

```py
from threading import Lock, Thread


def req1(lock: Lock, n: int):
    i = 0
    while i < 10:
        with lock:
            print(i % n)
            i += 1

def main():
    lock = Lock()
    n = 5
    tasks = [Thread(target=req1,args=(lock,n)) for i in range(n)]
    for i in tasks:
        i.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[correct output] Lock: use lock

```py
import time
from collections import deque
from threading import Lock, Thread


def req1(lock: Lock, data: deque):
    i = 0
    while i < 10:
        time.sleep(0.01)
        with lock:
            v = data.popleft()
            data.append(v)
            print(v)
            i += 1


def main():
    lock = Lock()
    data = deque([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
    tasks = [Thread(target=req1, args=(lock, data)) for i in range(5)]
    for i in tasks:
        i.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[correct output] threading: use event

```py
from threading import Event, Thread


def req1(e1: Event, e2: Event, count: int, char: str):
    while count > 0:
        e1.wait()
        e1.clear()
        print(char)
        e2.set()
        count -= 1


def main():
    count = 10
    e1, e2, e3, e4, e5 = Event(), Event(), Event(), Event(), Event()
    t1 = Thread(target=req1, args=(e1, e2, count, 0))
    t2 = Thread(target=req1, args=(e2, e3, count, 1))
    t3 = Thread(target=req1, args=(e3, e4, count, 2))
    t4 = Thread(target=req1, args=(e4, e5, count, 3))
    t5 = Thread(target=req1, args=(e5, e1, count, 4))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()
    t4.start()
    t5.start()
    e1.set()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[correct output] multiprocessing

```py
import time
from multiprocessing import Lock, Manager, Process
from typing import List


def req1(lock: Lock, data: List):
    i = 0
    while i < 10:
        time.sleep(0.01)
        with lock:
            v = data.pop(0)
            data.append(v)
            print(v)
            i += 1


def main():
    lock = Lock()
    data = Manager().list([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
    tasks = [Process(target=req1, args=(lock, data)) for i in range(5)]
    for i in tasks:
        i.start()
    for i in tasks:
        i.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[correct output] threading: use condition

```py
from threading import Condition, Thread
from typing import List


def req1(cond1: Condition, cond2: Condition, data: List, count: int):
    while count > 0:
        with cond1:
            cond1.wait()
            v = data.pop(0)
            print(v)
            data.append(v)
        with cond2:
            cond2.notify()
        count -= 1


def main():
    data = [0,1,2,3,4]
    n = len(data)
    conds = [Condition() for i in range(n)]
    tasks = []
    count = 10
    for i in range(n):
        tasks.append(Thread(target=req1, args=(
            conds[i], conds[0 if i == n-1 else i+1], data, count)))
    for i in tasks:
        i.start()

    with conds[0]:
        conds[0].notify()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: it works in ideal situation. But if I add `time.sleep(1)` inside `while` then I may get `0 0 0 ... 1 1 1 ... 2 2 2 ...` instead of `0 1 2 ... 0 1 2 ... 0 1 2 ...`

Comment: but my version works even worst :) it hangs when I add `time.sleep(1)` because processes use lock in different order then code expect and it locks all code.

Comment: @furas post updated

Comment: @furas If it is multiprocessing, I think this should be used `from multiprocessing import Lock`

Comment: code gives correct output - but it doesn't work as original code. You use `deque` to resolve problem - but if every process gets only one unique number then order can be wrong. But OP should decide if this is what he want - or if he want to use it for something more complex and it would need changes. At this moment I skip this question. Good luck.

Comment: @furas Regarding the author's question, your answer is undoubtedly the most accurate. I just provide some more solutions. In addition, regarding multi-process, I also wrote the code and updated the post.